# wWinMain control nCmdShow

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I have a windows command line demo application:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hpInstance, LPSTR nCmdLine, int nCmdShow){
  return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to control the `nCmdShow` variable when running a compiled version of it? My end goal is to conditionally run my application and attach it to a console or not. When attached to a console I want to print some messages. When not attached to a console, it should just run in the background and I want to avoid the black cmd window that appear temporary when calling `ShowWindow` within winMain.

When does the `nCmdShow` gets set?

Comment: It is specified by whatever program got your program started.  CreateProcess, STARTUPINFO.wShowWindow field.  Out of your reach.  You're not normally attached to a console when you have a WinMain() entrypoint.  Cmd.exe pays attention to the /SUBSYSTEM linker option that you used to link your program.  So does the OS, it isn't ShowWindow that displays the console.  In general you need to link two versions of your program, one that targets the console subsystem and one that doesn't.  You can give them the same name by creating an .exe and a .com

Comment: So, everything happens during the link time. You think there is no way linking a single exe and probably pass something like an environment to get the two behaviours out of a single executable, right?